# Am I now protected from replay attacks?

Tags: forks, replay-attack

I had five accounts on ETH before the hard fork with various balances. Over the last few days, I've sent all the ether in all of those accounts to Kraken. When I was done with that, all of my ether was in a brand new account (that did not exist prior to the fork). I then created a new account on Mist, and sent it all back to a brand new, did-not-exist-before-fork account in Mist. Am I now totally safe from replay attacks?

Also--just a side note--when I transferred to Kraken, ETHC magically appeared in my kraken account. I immediately sold it to US dollars and the bought new ETH, so the whole process was a net gain for me (assuming ETHC doesn't skyrocket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you assumed that Kraken does the split for you. I shortly looked up their official comm and it's confirmed

> If you have not yet split your ETH and ETC into different wallets and
>   are worried about the replay attack, you can safely make an ETH
>   deposit to Kraken. The transaction will automatically be replayed on
>   the ETC network if possible and you will receive both your ETH deposit
>   and an equal amount of ETC.

Because your now account for ETH does not exist on the ETC blockchain, you are safe from reply attacks. 
Even if you would have used the same ETH address you would be safe from reply attack as long somebody does not charge ETC on this address and you accidentally send it without reply protection through a split contract.

Comment: Yes. I was aware that Kraken was automatically replaying ETH transactions on ETC. The part of their statement "...replayed on the ETC network if possible..." tripped me up a bit. One ETH account thad about two ether less in it before the fork than it did when I first tried to move it. Therefore, on the ETC fork, the replay failed. I then sent all of those ETH back to my own account, and resent to Kraken, but this time only of the amount that was present before the fork. It worked this second time. The ETC showed up.